# add diagnostics at runtime not working (tutorial)

Tags: ros, diagnostics, ros-kinetic, diagnostic-aggregator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

When adding diagnostics at runtime using either the script manual_diag.py given here http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics/Tutorials/Adding%20Analyzers%20at%20Runtime or add_analyzers, the aggregator fails to properly update the group and leaves the added diagnostics under /Other/ even after wating for some time. The add_analyzers reports that the service call succeeded.

Looking at the logs, the aggregator gives:

```
[ WARN] [1519235533.166823508]: Bond for namespace /startup_analyzers was broken

[ WARN] [1519235533.171578828]: Broken bond tried to remove an analyzer which didn't exist.
```

I don't see any reasons why as the node adding diags (/startup_analyzers) is still running and I can see /diagnostics_agg/bond pub and sub when rostopic info. I'm running all of this on localhost.

The problem can be reproduced when following the tutorial [Adding Analyzers at Runtime](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics/Tutorials/Adding%20Analyzers%20at%20Runtime) at least on Kinetic@Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel 4.13.0.

There is only one node adding diags. Any idea or is that directly a Bond issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283386/add-diagnostics-at-runtime-not-working-(tutorial)/) by [Axel13fr](https://answers.ros.org/users/33814/axel13fr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So after digging into the https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/tree/indigo-devel/diagnostic_aggregator repository, I found the bug.

Some changes have been made on the diagnostic aggregator, specifically on the topic used to form the bond which is now "/diagnostics_agg/bond" + "add_diags node namespace".

This change has been made on the aggregator itself but only 2 months later on the add_diags script (so bond topic was not matching) and never in the tutorial.
I believe the kinetic release to this date has the changes made in the aggregator but not in the add_diags script, hence this bug.

I solved it by using the latest add_diags script on the github until it gets into kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [Axel13fr](https://answers.ros.org/users/33814/axel13fr/) with karma: 36 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1